# Go up a directory using \.. in string path - Python os.path

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, parent, os.path

I'm writing a post-job script for Thinkbox Deadline. I need the directory for the rendered frames from a finished Cinema 4D job.

In Cinema, we had the frames know to go up a few directories, then back down to a different location by using this syntax "path\to\c4d_file..\..\renders\frame_00.png"

In this example the "\.." tells Cinema to go up 2 folders to the "path" folder then back down into the "renders" folder where it saves the renders to.

Unfortunately Deadline doesn't calculate the actual path when it makes the render job. When I tell the post-job script to go to the path location, it doesn't understand the '\..' -- so I need to tell it where to go up a directory and where to go back down.

Is there any sort of Python magic that can basically read the "\.." and know how to make the correct directory?

Thanks

Comment: What actual code did you do to try and use `..`?

Comment: I just updated my post -- didn't realize SO would format the "\.." without the backslash. But to clarify "\.." is Cinema 4D's syntax to go up 1 directory, while the path after the "\.." will go back down the directory where you specify. I followed what Yohann suggested in the replies and got what I needed though, thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is an example of what I did that worked:
import os
path = r"path\to\folder\..\..\new\location"
new_path = os.path.abspath(path)
print(new_path)
#path\new\location

Answer (score 0):

Take the absolute path and remove the last one

```py
path.sep.join(path.abspath('.').split(path.sep)[:-1])
```

Comment: The first part of this resolved what I needed. I think all I needed was to use os.path.abspath(path_var) to make the path string remove the multiple "\..". The rest is good to know for future use though so thanks!